# Probability of survival in game of numbered blue and red balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, markov-chains

Say we have $n$ blue balls numbered as $1,2,3,\dots,n$, and $n$ red balls numbered as $-1,-2,-3,\dots,-n$. In each round of this game, we draw any of these $2n$ balls at random with replacement. If we at any point draw a ball, say number $j$, and have drawn ball $-j$ in a previous round, we lose. What is the probability of surviving for $m$ rounds?

For my own attempts at this, I considered the problem as a sequence of i.i.d. random variables $(X_k)_{k=1}^\infty$, each uniformly distributed on $\{ 1,-1,2,-2,\dots,n,-n\}$. Then for each $k$ put $B_k=\{ -X_1,-X_2,\dots,-X_k\}$. I am trying to find
\begin{align*}
&P(X_{j+1}\notin B_j\text{ for all }j=1,2,\dots,m-1) \\
&=P(X_2\notin B_1)\prod_{j=2}^{m-1}P(X_{j+1}\notin B_j\mid X_2\notin B_1,X_3\notin B_2,\dots,X_j\notin B_{j-1}).
\end{align*}
It is clear that $P(X_2\notin B_1)=P(X_2\neq -X_1)=1-(1/2n)$. For the remaining factors, it would be nice to utilize that
$$
P(X_{j+1}\in B_j\mid\# B_j=l)=\frac{l}{2n}.
$$
If I could only show that $1(X_{j+1}\in B_j)$ and $(1(X_{k+1}\in B_k))_{k=1}^{j-1}$ are independent conditioned on $\# B_j$, which I believe to be the case, then we would have
$$
P(X_{j+1}\notin B_j\mid X_2\notin B_1,X_3\notin B_2,\dots,X_j\notin B_{j-1})=\sum_{l=1}^j P(X_{j+1}\notin B_j\mid\# B_j=l)P(\# B_j=l)=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{l=1}^j lP(\# B_j=l).
$$
There is some hope to find $P(\# B_j=l)$, as $(\# B_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ is a Markov chain with fairly simple transition probabilities:
$$
P(\# B_{k+1}=l\mid\# B_k=l)=\frac{l}{2n}=1-P(\# B_{k+1}=l+1\mid\# B_k=l). 
$$
I can see that $X_{j+1}$ is independent of $(1(X_{k+1}\in B_k))_{k=1}^{j-1}$, both unconditionally and conditioned on $\# B_j$, but I can't get the full independence that I need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To clarify:  It's fine if you draw the *same* number again, you just can't draw the negative of one you have seen? That complicates things...even if $m=3$ you need to distinguish the case in which you draw the same ball twice in a row.  For higher $m$, the possible cases get quite complex.

Comment: Yes exactly. If the problem was not drawing the same ball, this would simply be the birthday problem, no?

Comment: Very similar, in any case.  As it stands, I think the Markov approach you describe is best.  At least that should let you compute the answer for respectably large $m$.

Comment: "and have drawn ball $−j$
 in a previous round, we lose." *Any* earlier round  ?

Comment: Yes, any of the earlier rounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not sure why you’re taking this hybrid approach – it may be that I don’t understand it properly. I’ll solve the problem in two ways in which I’d approach it, and I hope that will also throw some light on what you’re trying to do.

First, we can get the desired probability by [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

We’re only allowed to draw one of the two numbers from each pair. There are $2^n$ ways to pick a number from each pair, and then we have probability $\left(\frac12\right)^m$ to draw only those $n$ numbers.

But that double-counts the cases where we don’t actually draw from some pair. There are $\binom n{n-1}$ ways to choose $n-1$ pairs to draw from and $2^{n-1}$ ways to pick a number from each of them, and then we have probability $\left(\frac{n-1}{2n}\right)^m$ to draw only those $n-1$ numbers.

But if we subtract that probability, we’ve now undercounted the cases where we don’t actually draw from two pairs. Continuing with this inclusion–exclusion yields the probability

$$
\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{n-j}2^j\binom nj\left(\frac j{2n}\right)^m
$$

to survive $m$ rounds.

Alternatively, we can use a Markov chain. There are $n+2$ different states: One absorbing state where we’ve lost, and $n+1$ transient states in which $k$ with $0\le k\le n$ different numbers have been drawn that don’t include any pairs of additive inverses.

In transient state $k$, the probability to lose is $\frac k{2n}$, the probability to stay in the state $k$ is also $\frac k{2n}$, and the probability to transition to the state $k+1$ is $1-\frac{2k}{2n}$. Thus the transition matrix is given by

$$
\vec p\to\pmatrix{
0&0&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\
1&\frac1{2n}&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\
0&1-\frac2{2n}&\frac2{2n}&0&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&1-\frac4{2n}&\frac3{2n}&0&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\ddots&\ddots\\
0&0&\cdots&&\frac2{2n}&\frac n{2n}&0\\
0&\frac1{2n}&\frac2{2n}&\frac3{2n}&\cdots&\frac n{2n}&1
}\vec p\;.
$$

Since this is a lower triangular matrix, the eigenvalues are the diagonal elements, $1$ and $\lambda_k=\frac k{2n}$ for $0\le k\le n$. The corresponding eigenvectors are $\vec v_{n+1}=(0,\ldots,0,1)^\top$ for the eigenvalue $1$ and

$$
v_{kj}=\begin{cases}
(-1)^{n-j}2^{j-k}\binom{n-k}{n-j}&0\le j\le n
\\
-1&j=n+1
\end{cases}
$$

for the eigenvalue $\lambda_k$. The initial distribution $\vec p=(1,0,\ldots,0)^\top$ decomposes into these eigenvectors according to

$$
\vec p=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}2^k\binom nk\vec v_k+\vec v_{n+1}\;,
$$

so the probability to survive $m$ rounds is

$$
1-\left(\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}2^k\binom nk\lambda_k^m\vec v_k+\vec v_{n+1}\right)_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}2^k\binom nk\left(\frac k{2n}\right)^m\;,
$$

in agreement with the result from inclusion–exclusion.

Comment: I'm spoiled; two solutions! Thank you for your insights. I'm not sure there's much more to be understood about my attempted solution. I was going after something like your second solution, and I have also written (some of) the corresponding transition probabilities -- I just didn't think to add the absorbing state in such an elegant way as you did. After seeing your solutions, I can see why you describe my approach as hybrid. In any case, I feel my understanding has been improved, so thank you again!